# More than 1 exception handler for same error code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There is some Spring Boot app.
Is there possible to have 2 different exception handlers based on URL for same web error (for example error code 400) returning 2 different responses?
Something like this

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Error400HandlerAdvice1 extends BaseHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseClass1 handleBadRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        if(req.getRequestURI().contains("mykeyword1")) { 
            ResponseClass1 ret=ResponseClass1();
            return ret;
        } 
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class Error400HandlerAdvice2 extends BaseHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseClass2 handleBadRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        if(req.getRequestURI().contains("mykeyword2")) { 
            ResponseClass2 ret=ResponseClass2();
            return ret;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need 2 controller advice classes in this scenario.
Just create one:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Error400HandlerAdvice extends BaseHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        if (req.getRequestURI().contains("mykeyword1")) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ResponseClass1());
        } else if (req.getRequestURI().contains("mykeyword2")) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ResponseClass2());
        } else {
            // Handle other cases if necessary
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new DefaultErrorResponse());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , but with this proposition , there is some issue with generated Swagger data : for error 400 I get empty sample response ( {} )

Comment: It sounds like a different issue and question, I would try to handle this scenario in Swagger using `@ApiOperation` or `@ApiResponses` and provide all the necessary details.